# Add version button in iTunes Connect is disabled

Tags: ios, version, app-store-connect

The 'Add New Version' button on the iTunes Connect app page is disabled.

How do I enable that? I want to release an update to the app.

PFA screen shot of the page.[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is because you already have a tvOS version in "Prepare for submission" state and iOS version in "Developer Rejected" state.

The Add Version button will be enabled if any one or all of your app platform(s) latest version is in "Ready for Sale" state.

> You will only be able to add a new version for a new platform or a
>   platform that has a Ready for Sale or Developer Removed from Sale
>   version. If a platform version has not completed the app review
>   process—it has a status such as Prepare For Submission or Waiting For
>   Review—you can replace the build in the existing version instead of
>   adding a new version.

Reference : [Replacing Your App With A New Version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html)